Using HAVING without GROUP BY in SQL
I know this will not work but can someone explain why?
SELECT * 
FROM employees 
HAVING salary = MAX(salary);

The code does not work with WHERE clause because it's filtering against an aggregate result. My understanding is that HAVING should work with aggregate functions. Why does this not work?

It does indeed work with aggregate functions, but without a group by you don't have an aggregate function.

If your intention is to get all (individual) rows in the employees table where the salary is equal to the highest salary in the entire table, the correct query is:
select *
from employees
where salary=(select max(salary) from employees)

HAVING clause is used in conjunction with the GROUP BY clause to aggregate individual rows into 'groups', and then applying a criteria to those groups (therefore HAVING requires GROUP BY)

The HAVING clause requires the GROUP BY clause because it filters data that the GROUP BY clause produces. The GROUP BY clause groups rows with the same values into summary rows, and the HAVING clause then filters those groups.
If you want the max salary across the entire table then you could do this:
select max(salary) from employees;


The group by clause "aggregates" data.

You can have HAVING clause without GROUP BY. For example : select count(*) from Employee having count(*) > 100

There an implicit aggregation in that case, because you can't select * instead of select count(*)

--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table tbl (id Int, val Int);
Insert Into tbl Values
      ( 1, 100 ), 
      ( 2, 200 ), 
      ( 3, 300 ), 
      ( 4, 400 ), 
      ( 5, 500 );

1. Having clause filters resultset after aggregation and the columns used in condition should be either aggregated or grouped by
Select   *
From     tbl
Having   Max(val) = val


Column 'tbl.val' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

2. Selecting * is selecting list of all columns. When used with aggregation (Having clause here) all columns selected should be either aggregated or listed in Group By clause.
Select   *
From     tbl
Having   Max(val) = 500


Column 'tbl.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Working samples:
Select *
From   tbl
Where val = ( Select Max(val) From tbl )

/*  R e s u l t :
id  val
--  ---
 5  500    */

Select Max(val) as max_val
From   tbl
Having Max(val) = ( Select Max(val) From tbl )  -- equales value fetched by query
/* OR */
Having Max(val) = 500  -- equals fixed hardcoded value

which is the same (with this sample data) as ...
Select Max(val) as max_val
From   tbl

/*    R e s u l t :
max_val
-------
    500    */

More about the subject here.
